# Правильно ли то что слово "обожженною" является прилагательным, а слово "обгоревшею" - причастием?

Tags: морфология, прилагательные, недопустимая-метка, причастия

Явился его староста, верхом, с обожженною щекой и обгоревшею бородой.

Answer (score 2):

1. Глагольные признаковые формы изначально являются причастиями, но могут переходить в прилагательные (такой переход называется адъективизацией).
2. Страдательные причастия прошедшего времени на НЫЙ чаще других переходят в прилагательные, но это касается в основном двух групп: 
   А) жаренный в масле – жареный - прилагательное соотносится с  бесприставочным глаголом несовершенного вида, имеет значение результата действия и обозначает постоянный признак;
   Б) взволнованный человек – взволнованное лицо, образованное слово – образованные люди – переносное значение, нельзя подобрать зависимое слово в Т.п. , обозначающее производителя действия.
3. Если причастия не имеют указанных признаков, как в заданном примере, то они   не переходят в прилагательные. Обожженный – это причастие, обозначающее признак как действие, завершенное на момент речи, а не постоянный признак. Значение прямое, а не переносное.

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу разницы. С обожженною щекой - с щекой, которую обожгло на пожаре огнём, её обожгли - это не постоянное качество, это признак по действию обжечь - причастие.

С обгоревшею бородой -  с бородой, которая обгорела-причастие.

Вот здесь о разнице причастий и прилагательных: 
http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=199902601

причастия
(взволновать мать) взволнованная мать
(измучить путника) измученный путник
(утомить человека) утомленный человек

прилагательные
взволнованный голос (выражающий волнение, его никто не волновал)
изумленный вид (выражающий изумление, вид сам по себе такой, его никто не изумлял)
утомленное лицо(выражающее утомление, его никто не утомлял)